# I am trying not to lose my marbles

Tags: physics

I have made some glass marbles and a glass jar. Then dropped the marbles into the jar using the physics settings. I then I have a jar full of marbles which is what I wanted. However, I can't seem to make this into an item which is a jar of marbles, without the physics, which I can append to another scene etc. When I do this, sometimes I get it to work but then I try to move the collection (Marbles and jar) and the marbles disappear from the jar.
I was trying to use physics and my simple models to create a jar full of marbles, to use in other scenes.
(sorry for the question, but it is what is happening)

Comment: if you don't need the physics anymore, you could bake so that you can manipulate the jar + marble as ordinary objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your desired frame, when your objects have fallen into place, (I just let some cubes fall below the Z axis) select all of your marbles.

Use the search function <kbd>F3</kbd> to find *Object* -> *Rigid Body* -> *Apply Transformation*, this will set the marbles' transforms to the same locations as their position in the rigid body sim.

[image]

Now search for *Object* -> *Rigid Body* -> *Remove*.  **This step will fail if you do not have an active selection (one object with light orange outline)**  You can shift click one of your marbles to deselect it and then select it again to make it the active selection in your selection group.

[image]

When this command is run successfully, the physics should be removed from all of your marbles, and then you can manipulate them and parent the jar as usual.